# What are the ways to reduce bundle size on iOS?

Tags: ios

I have some images which are huge in size and my bundle size currently is 70 MB. I think Xcode already runs the assets through png crush.

Comment: What kind of images do you have? How big is the biggest one? How do you create these images?

Comment: Remove some images and/or reduce their size...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try converting the images to jpg (if they don't have any transparent regions).
Also try using http://imageoptim.com/

Answer (score 5):

- Do not use any **text images** with useless effects, use `UILabel`s instead.
- Draw simple shapes and effects using `CAShapeLayer`s instead of using
  images.
- Use **JPEGs** instead of **PNGs** where you don't need transparency.
  *(Actually file size depends on the image content here)*
- Use **Save for Web** option in **PhotoShop** or other tools to **optimize** PNG
  images.
- Use **sprites** combined together instead of separate images.
- Make sure you **delete all unused** resources.
- Do not localize common parts of the images, localize only the
  **different parts**. *(think of a background image with a small flag at
  the bottom for each locale. use one single bg image and separate flag
  images. localize flag images only, not the entire bg images with the
  flags.)*
- Use the **same splash images** for iOS7 and previous iOS versions. *(You
  need to manually edit the JSON file in .xcassets)*
- Try using a **CDN to download** assets on the **first launch**.

In addition to images keep those in mind too:

- Try replacing **custom fonts** with default system fonts if you don't
  need them really.
- Use **MP3** audio files instead of **WAV** files. *(or other
  compressed formats)*
- Make sure you **delete all unused** 3rd party frameworks.

Comment: These recommendations seem to be much more reasonable than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very unlikely that you actually need huge images. After all, the *screen* is not huge. Thus, the most likely form of size reduction is to reduce the physical dimensions of the images to the size you are actually going to be displaying.

This saves bandwidth when the user downloads the image, reduces the size of the app on the user's hard disk (the device), and also saves memory at the time an image is loaded. It is a vast waste of RAM to load an image that is larger than the size at which it will be displayed; after all, remember, the memory involved rises exponentially with the *square* of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to host the images on a CDN like OpenText and fetch them as part of app initialization, or whenever they are first needed.  Obviously this is more coding, but projects like SDWebImage make it pretty easy:

`https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/master/SDWebImage`

It also gives you the flexibility to swap out those images later if you use caching headers.